# Keyboard not retracting under IOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, ios5

I have a an app which has worked perfectly well until the release of IOS 5. I've managed to fix most of the problems caused by the upgrade but I cannot get the keyboard to retract. My other apps manage to do it ok under IOS 5 but I'm missing something with this app. The app scrolls though a large Pdf and the textField is to take the user to a specific page. When the keyboard appears it covers the textField and only the Pdf is visible. Under 4.2 the keyboard retracts when the Pdf is pressed but that doesn't work with IOS 5. I'm using the code below but it doesn't get called, whereas in my other apps which retract the keyboard successfully the code is called, what am I missing.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     if(textField == pageNo){
    [pageNo resignFirstResponder];
     }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the callback itself not getting called, or is the if condition not passing?

Comment: if nobody else answers this question, I'll try to :-)  It might be useful to attach a screenshot of your User Interface.  It sounds like you have a PDF in the top half of your screen and a text field in the bottom half (since it's getting covered by the keyboard).  Which doesn't seem like a very good user interface.  What kind of object is the PDF view?  And when you click on it, does the text field get a `textFieldDidEndEditing` callback?  Did you properly set a delegate on the text field?

Comment: The callback itself is not called at all, I put a breakpoint on the first condition and it never gets used. Your description of the app is about right and I guess the design is not ideal but it sits on the toolbar at the bottom along with the navigation keys, so I've kept them all together. The toolbar has the buttun << < > >> as well as an Index and of course the textField for typing the page number you want to go to. I added textFieldDidEndEditing and that didn't get called either. Your last comment sounds like it could be the reason, I set the delegate on the text Field to File's Owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix idea? put this in the pdf view touch handler?

`if ([pageNo isFirstResponder]) [pageNo resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm using a webView to display the Pdf which doesn't have any touch handlers. If you touch the webView/Pdf in any other IOS than IOS 5 it retracts without problem

Comment: Managed to find a way round it on the lines above. I used the Did End On Exit Event to call an IBAction which used resignFirstResponder on the textField. It isn't very pretty but it worked.